# I cannot su - into my root account from a normal user

Tags: linux, permissions, root, administration

I can't switch normal user to root and I get following error:

```
    [user2@server1 ~]$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I know for a fact that password is correct.

Also permissions on my su file are correct for su

`[user2@server1 ~]$ ll /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 32032 Mar 28  2014 /bin/su`

And every time I try to log in and it gets declined I see following messages in /var/log/secure file

```
    'Nov  2 14:17:54 server1 su: pam_unix(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname=user2 uid=1000 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser=user2 rhost=  user=root
Nov  2 14:17:54 server1 su: pam_succeed_if(su-l:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root'
```

Now I don't really understand these messages. I feel like its pointing towards username with UID 1000. By mistake I think I deleted my username "user 1" and It was attached to UID 1000. Now system won't even let me add a user id user1 saying it already exist and won't even let me delete it!

```
    [root@server1 ~]# useradd user1
useradd: user 'user1' already exists 
[root@server1 ~]# userdel -r user1
userdel: user user1 is currently used by process 3300 
user2     3300  3288  0 14:27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: user2@pts/1
```

Need Help!

added user3 and tried su - with that

```
[user3@server1 ~]$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
[user3@server1 ~]$ id
uid=1001(user3) gid=1001(user3) groups=1001(user3) context=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0
```

added user2 and system automatically assigned it UID 1000 but its not working either

```
[user2@server1 ~]$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

This is weird

```
[user2@server1 ~]$ id user1
uid=1000(user2) gid=1000(user2) groups=1000(user2)
[user2@server1 ~]$ id user2
uid=1000(user2) gid=1000(user2) groups=1000(user2)
```

Here is how my su file looks like

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/su
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        substack    system-auth
auth        include     postlogin
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     include     postlogin
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

I have also tried to remove "so uid = 0" but same result

Comment: `sudo su`, maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, I have two other machines as well and I always use su -. Other Two machines are working fine and this one was working okay till now!

Comment: Your best bet is to assign this user's UID to something expected, like 1000.  To make such a change, I would expect you would need to be root.  It is clear that you're having troubles logging in as root from this user, but can you log in as root using any other user (including a completely different user that you create)?  Try: "useradd user3", and go from there?  If you type "id user1", just what UID is assigned to "user1"?

Comment: Thanks TOOGRAM for the comment. I have updated my question for you. Please see last two codes.

Comment: Alright guys, I am able to resolve one issue, I commented sss lines in /etc/nsswitch.conf and was able to remove user1 and re-added it and now user1 and user2 have different UID's. User2 has 1000. But still can't su- with any user id.

Comment: UID>=1000 is a red herring: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2013-March/432995.html

Answer (score 3):

In your `pam.d` configuration (`/etc/pam.d/`) you're probably doing UID check somewhere, or it has been added automatically. The problem happens when the user doing `su -` has an ID over 1000, which in your case is true; then pam.d will reject your `su -` attempt.

Look at the mentioned directory and find a file containing something like this:

```
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
```

(Might vary, the important part is `uid >= 1000`).

If you find it, simply delete the checking part. So if you find a line like the above, change it to:

```
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success
```

No need to restart anything, the `su -` command should work immediately after.

Comment: Thanks nKn, I don't have line similar to that in my pam file and I have also compared my pam file with other machines I have and its exactly same where su - is working. I have edited the question and you can see my pam file there.

Comment: But I meant not only the `su` file, but *any* file you might have here. You can use `cd /etc/pam.d && grep uid *` to see if some file has that line.

Comment: **I compared all files with the other machines I have and there is no difference but I have been able to resolve the issue atleast for now. I have disabled selinux and now I can su - into root with any user. I am not sure whats wrong with selinux but I am good 4 now. Thanks everyone who have contributed!** @nKn